# background process in java listening to stdin

Tags: java, shell, stdin, background-process

I have to make a java program that when user enters 0 it should exit. no problem writing in java code.

```
int cmd = read();
System.out.println("got command : " + cmd);
if (cmd == 48) { // ASCII code for 0
System.exit(0);
```

I want to run this process using start-stop script in linux. I am also being able to do that using `&` or `nohup`

```
case "$1" in    
  'start')
    if [ -f myfifo ]; then
      rm myfifo
    fi
    mkfifo myfifo
    cat > myfifo &
    echo $! > myfifo-cat-pid
    java -jar myjar.jar >/dev/null 2>&1 0<myfifo &
    echo "Started process: "$!
    ;;

  'stop')
    echo 0 > myfifo
    echo "Stopped process: "
    rm myfifo
    ;;
esac
```

My problem is as soon as i run this process it read input -1. While I want to read from stdinput when somthing is echoed to it explicitly i.e. stop is called. Simply i need a program to be closed by shell script explicitly. I have tried hard. Help me.

Edit :

I just want to close the program when user press q or any such event and dont want infinite loop in code. Any other approach like listening to other events will also help if possible. My code should not be polling for event. I have tried `Jnotify` which watch a directory and rise an event when file is created or deleted in that directory. But hard luck they dont have support for SunOS. :(

Comment: using System.in.read(); Also i have tried it using BufferReader

Comment: hum... Are you sure the myfifo exists and contains anything in there ? System.in.read() is meant to work fine... what does the `mkfifo`?

Comment: mkfifo creates a fifo(queue). System.in .read() is reading even if i dont assign any stdin for process.

Comment: my understanding is that as there is nothing yet in the fifo, then it reaches the EOF. Try to create the fifo and push some value in it before starting you java program, just to ensure it is working fine when there is something to read.

Comment: Did you check if `myfifo` exists? can you read from it?

Comment: @Abhishekbhutra I don't have linux here, but my understanding of http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo is that this is a particular type of file that is probably not handled "normally", could you please give a try with a regular file to ensure you java program is working fine?

Comment: @vainolo myfifo file exists and i can read from it to.

Comment: @ZNK-M i have tried with regular file too. then i moved to fifo reading this http://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `set -m` at the top of your shell script (hence enabling forcefully job control), you should see a consistent behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in fact the `fifo` files seems not behave exactly as you imagine.

The `read()` command is not blocking on a pipe. You should loop until you get data:

```
    try {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
        while (true) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            if (bis.available() > 0) {
                bis.read(buffer, 0, bis.available());
                // do some clever thing
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // it failed...
    }
```

This will try to read and if there is nothing, then it will wait for 50 ms.

M.

Comment: I forget to mention i have also done this using while loop but then it will continuously read from stdin that i dont want beacause its an infinte loop till user sends right command. :(

Comment: What is your need? do something in your program and listen the stdin at the same time? And when the user press "q" it stops your program?

Comment: yes that is waht i need. But program should running in background

Comment: Then you must split your code into two threads. One that will listen the fifo and set a variable to true if the program must exit. And the other that will do the job and checks every loop if it can continue or if it must stop now.

Comment: yes, both in fact. As you want them to run as background process, they must be in an infinite mode. STDIN Thread loops until there is something to reads, then sleeps, reads, sleeps, ... and the other Thread do the job, check if it must stops, do the job, checks, ...

Comment: then single while loop will better... :)

Comment: probably, depends on what your are doing, long job, that can be interrupted or not, ... it is up to you!

Comment: thanks for help..then i guess there is no way to do so without loop

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no data in the pipe yet, `read()` sees the end of the stream and because of this it returns `-1`. Call `available()` before reading from the stream to be sure that there is information in it.

Answer (score 0):

When you background a command in a script the stdin of that command gets implicitly redirected from `/dev/null`.

```
# test by executing a script with ...
- cat > myfifo & lsof -p $!
+ cat 0<&0 > myfifo & lsof -p $!
```